# Stumped on applying function to all li items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, loops

This might be a dumb question. I looked on the site for an answer but might not be searching correctly.

```
<ul>
   <li id="tab1">1</li>
   <li id="tab2">2</li>
   <li id="tab3">3</li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to write code that will let on tab fade out of the `li` when clicked.  Is there a way to write the code one time and have it apply to all 3 `li`s. I am not sure if I am even remotely in the right direction.  I was thinking I need to use an “if statement” and this is what I have so far...

```
(function() {
    var lists = $("ul li");

      for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
    {    
         buttons[i].onclick=(function(){      
         var n = i,
         tabs = $("#tab");  

       return function(){
        tabs + n.click.fadeOut(500) })

         })
    }
})
```

I know this is far from correct but I am completely stumped on this. Would there be a better way to go about doing this. Thanks for the help

Comment: So each `li` is a button? You don't need to loop over them. jQuery can assign the function to all of them at the same time. (you should use jQuery's `click()` instead of your own).  However you appear to have more than one `#tab` id which won't work. Unless you want all the buttons to work on the same tab ...

Comment: where is the markup for the tabs

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your code is attempting to do, but this will fade an item on click. Based on the names I assume you're trying to fade a corresponding tab - show me that tab html and I'll update this answer.

```
$("ul").on("click", "li", function() {
   //guess on fading the tab:
   $("#tabs div").not("." + this.id).fadeOut(500);//fadeout other tabs
   $("#tabs ." + this.id).fadeIn(500); //fade in this tab
})
```

This will fadeout all tabs and fadein the clicked tab if your tab html is like:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <div class="tab1">1</div>
    <div class="tab2">2</div>
    <div class="tab3">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I *think* he wants to fade some other element when the `li` is clicked but you're right it's not clear.

Comment: `$("#tabs").not` implies more than one `$("#tabs")` which can't be a duplication of ID, and nothing in your markup has an ID to support the other selector creation. Need to refine your code

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @charlietfl. I missed that when I type this out

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The answer is simpler than you think. At the very core, it is how to identify a variable amount of lists. Some potential solutions:

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li id="tab1" class="tab">1</li>
    <li id="tab2" class="tab">2</li>
    <li id="tab3" class="tab">3</li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$(".tab").click(function() {
    $(this). //do a function
});
```

There are many alternate ways too, this one is straightforward for your purpose I think though. You can also put in `value=2` and so on to list items, and use those to identify values, and then to act on a variable ID, use code like `$('#tab'+varValue).fadeOut('slow')` or whatever function after targeting it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what larger goal you're trying to accomplish, but this will do as you seem to have asked:

```
$('li').click(function() {
   $(this).fadeOut(500);
});
```

For each member of the jQuery matched set (here, all three `li` elements), assign a click function to each one. Upon click, the `this` reference will refer to the clicked item--so you can just wrap it into a jQuery object, and fade it out. The `li` elements will fade out on click.

If you are trying to accomplish something else, please describe it in more detail so we can help you more.

A few other style notes for you:

- There is no need to loop, `click` already assigns a click handler to each element in the jQuery object.
- There is no need to use `onclick` as jQuery's `click` does that for you.
- Don't create functions inside a loop. It may look like the above code does exactly that, but it doesn't: it creates one instance of the function, which is passed into the `click` method. Inside a `for` loop, you actually create a new instance of the function each time, which is not best practice.
- Returning a function from an `onclick` handler function isn't going to do anything.
- Since an `li` *must* be inside a `ul`, there is no need to increase selector complexity by looking for `'ul li'`--just look for `'li'`.
- Note that many javascript developers use single quotes for strings in JS so that embedded HTML can use double quotes.